# Running Pine/Alpine within a Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, email, shell, powershell, console

I am attempting to move most of my  daily working life to a terminal shell. I am a .NET dev so I run on WinXP purely for visual studio (just wait until I get better at Emacs). I would really much like it if I could use an email client within a terminal (either using Console or PowerShell within Console).

From my uni days I know of only pine and so this is what I tried to get for windows. However, I could only find two variants, PC-Pine and Alpine for Windows. Both of these provide the mail functions I want and they can connect to my domain exchange server BUT I cannot get them to launch with the shell I am using (Console with PowerShell).

My question: Is there anyone out there running Windows that uses a console mail client that can run in PowerShell or Console2 which has the same or similar functionality to Pine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to READ email from either the Windows CMD line or Powershell, your best bet it to try and get one of the UNIX-style Terminal email clients to work using CGYWIN as the front end. You might want to try [MUTT](http://www.mutt.org/download.html) or the [Softabar CMD EMail Client](http://softabar-command-line-email-client.findmysoft.com/) but I haven't tried either one myself.

However, if all you want is SEND email, then that's easy :)

I use Powershell to send emails using the following snippit. This could very easily be put into a script or pasted into your **$Profile** file to allow you to send emails on the fly.

```
$emailFrom = "sender"
$emailTo = "recipient"
$subject = "Your subject"
$body = "Your Message"
$smtpServer = "smtp.server.com"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body)
```

You could even wrap this in a "Send-Mail" cmdlet and call it using the parameters whenever you want, for example `Send-Mail("ivan@stackoverflow","dbarrett83@stackoverflow","I answered your question","Hey man, answered you question on SO...go check it out. 'n. Talk to you later - Dan")`. Just make sure to use **'n** (the accent key under the tilde followed by the lowercase 'n') for line breaks.

I hope this helps!

~Dan